# Spring: GCP and JPA - Missing EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa, google-cloud-platform

I have a working implementation of Spring Boot with Tomcat that handles fine in a JAR file within a Linux environment.  The same code fails to work with Google Cloud.  I'm trying to get JPA to work.

Google Cloud prefers Jetty over Tomcat.  This may relate to my issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  I have the default recommended conversion from a standard Spring Boot JAR to a WAR version for Google Cloud's AppEngine.  My dependencies work fine if I try them in a pre-set project from the spring.io site.  I'm not using databases, so I cut out MySQL, which is default.

My problem relates to a missing ***EntityManagerFactory***.  Since I'm trying to keep this post brief, I just include what I think is vital.  You can find the essentials to the complete project at:  https://github.com/shatterblast/spring-sylveria_fix-search

Basically, I can't bring up the Admin Console for this GCP project.  The project and the Admin Console both respond with a 503 from a request.  There is no error message during startup, and it executes fine.  From tweaking the code, I found the ***EntityManager*** bean as the problem itself.  Re-naming beans has not helped.

Thank you.

```
import com.weslange.springboot.sylveria.entity.Gamer;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@Repository
public class GamerDAOHibernateImpl implements GamerDAO {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public GamerDAOHibernateImpl( EntityManager theEntityManager ) {
        entityManager = theEntityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Gamer findById( int id ) {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );
        Gamer gamer = currentSession.get( Gamer.class, id );
        return gamer;
    }

    @Override
    public void save( Gamer gamer ) {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate( gamer );
    }

}
```

.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@Repository
public class TokenDAOHibernateImpl implements TokenDAO {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public TokenDAOHibernateImpl(EntityManager theEntityManager) {
        entityManager = theEntityManager;
    }

}
```

.

```
import com.weslange.springboot.sylveria.SylveriaServerApplication;
import com.weslange.springboot.sylveria.entity.Token;
import com.weslange.springboot.sylveria.service.GamerService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


@RestController
@RequestMapping( "/" )
public class TokenRestController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( SylveriaServerApplication.class );

    private GamerService gamerService;

    @Autowired
    public TokenRestController( GamerService gamerService ) {
        gamerService = gamerService;
    }

    @PostMapping( "/" )
    public HashMap addEmployee( @RequestBody Token token, HttpServletRequest request ) {

        HashMap<String, String> returnMap = new HashMap();
        returnMap.put( "sylveriaConnectionSuccess", "true" );

        return returnMap;

    }

}
```

Comment: which compute solution do you use? AppEngine? std/flex ? Which runtime? Springboot with JPA is working fine with GAE Std Java 8 and 11. Please could you provide more details on GCP hosting.

Comment: AppEngine with Standard.  I'm using the WAR version for a runtime meant for Jetty.  This case only includes AppEngine Standard, and nothing else.  This is from testing ran on Google SDK's emulator on my local machine.

Comment: Wes, several questions : which db are you using ? There isn't any configuration in your code. Why do you use EntityManager, it could be transparent with @Repository. I think you encounter multiple issues. What about first trying to deploy a working Spring Boot app without JPA, and then try to add it. In both case, I can give you some example. And last question, could you consider to use Java 11?, it will be easier with GAE now with latest runtime.

Comment: I explain this in my post already, but I shall repeat.  There is no database.  Again, it's GCP with nothing else.  No database.  It works fine as a JAR with Tomcat.  It fails as a WAR with Jetty.  Also, the problem is not solved if I try switching between Java 8 and 11.  By default, the project uses Java 8 compatibility.  I use EntityManager, because it works with the JAR file and Tomcat just fine.

Comment: No example exists to use JPA without a database for GCP.  Everything requires a connector to MySQL or similar.  Again, I don't want to use a database. GCP Datastore is not part of my project.

Comment: What would be the specific use of JPA if you are not requiring the use of a Database?

Comment: I perform my own implementation of the REST API.  Hibernate supports this.

Comment: Could you please deploy as following : " gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug " and share the output ?